# Products not showing up in Magento search, but are on website

Tags: magento, search, product

I'm having major issues with my search function in Magento, the products are showing up in some searches, in the main categories, but when I search for the specific product model number (which most customers will search for).

For example searching for a YAMAHA PSR-E233 61-KEY PORTABLE KEYBOARD if I type in Keyboard it comes up under that category, but if I search 'PSR' which most people would search, it says 'no products to show' - which is areal issue for our site.

Apologies I am new to web development in generally and am learning Magento, I have spent all afternoon searching for this and have not been able t fix it, I have tried all the obvious settings in Magento that I have come across, such as 
Please check following settings are done for your product

- The products must be Visible in Catalog.
- The products must be Enabled.
- Product must have a stock Quantity.
- The product must be set to In Stock.
- If the product is set not to track stock, it still need to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
- The product must be assigned to the target Category.
- If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
- You must refresh your “var/Cache” & rebuild all indexes from admin > system > index management

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **visibility** attribute on the product to `catalog, search`. That will make sure the product can be found.

You also need to set which attributes are searchable. Go into the **attributes admin page** under catalog. Then find the attribute you want (SKU I'm guessing). Inside that change the **Use in Quick Search** and **Use in Advanced Search** options to **Yes**

Comment: Thanks for your response - I've already done this, as the products show up in some general searches, but not when I types specific parts of the product name or codes. Turned out that the indexing wasn't working properly, so I re indexed everything manually through SSH and now it works fine - thanks :-)